# Run function of one angular controller in another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have page with 2 lists: categories and products for that category. Module code:

```
var shop = angular.module('shop', []);

shop.controller('Products', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', function($scope, $http, $rootScope) {

    $scope.products = []; 

    $scope.update = function () {       
        $http.post('/shop/products', {
            category_id: $rootScope.category_id
        })
            .success(function(response, status){
               $scope.products = response.data;
            })
            .error(function(data, status){  });
        };
    }]);

shop.controller('Categories', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', function($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
    $scope.categories = [
        { name: 'games', id: 1 }, { name: 'films', id: 2 } 
    ]
    $rootScope.category_id = '-1';
    $scope.select = function (id) {
        $rootScope.category_id = id;

        // Need to run an update of Product controller

    }
}]);
```

When a user selects the category by clicking on it, I need to update products list with new products (filtered by selected category) that I received from a server. And the question is **How to run update function of Products controller in Categories controller?**

I know about easy-way with event broadcastings, but it is not the best solution.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please ask a question. This doesn't really entail a question. Do you need help with factories? Do you want people to review your code? Your description is also extremely localized. We don't know what projects you're working on. But we are programmers so we know about data types, structs, algorithms etc. Phrase this so that people can quickly see what type of issue you're having rather than concentrating on the minute details of your specific assignment. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, franklin. I updated question and made it very simple and clear.

Comment: You should use a service to share the information between multiple controllers or as you said setting up a set of emit/broadcast events. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&t=26m41s or more specifically http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&t=28m06s

Comment: Yes, by service I can access data in any controller, but I can't update scope of one controller from another (only by events)